# How to use Properties of an item in a collection using SmartFormat.NET

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, template-engine, smartformat.net

I am trying to use SmartFormat and I have an issue with it. I am using the following format

`"{SelectedUsers:| {User.FirstName} is selected for '{Job.Summary} job. ', }"` and I am expecting that the output will be like following for each item. (If the first item in the collection has values 'Joe' as User.FirstName and 'witch hunting' as Job.Summary )

> "Joe is selecting for 'witch hunting' job."

and so on display other items in the selected users collection. But the output is

> { User = { FirstName = Test }, Job = { Summary = Job Summary } }

I am not sure if my syntaxt is wrong or the given feature is not implemented in SmartFormat. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the object layout as well as the calling code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your syntax is wrong.  The [List Formatting syntax](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat.NET/wiki/List-Formatting-Syntax) is `{[selector]:[itemFormat]|[spacer]|[finalSpacer]}`, but your `|` looks to be in the wrong place.

This ought to work:

```
"{SelectedUsers:{User.FirstName} is selected for '{Job.Summary}' job|, |, and }."
//-collection--:---------- repeated for each item ------------------|-spacer-|-finalSpacer-}
```

This would output something like:

```
"Joe is selected for 'witch hunting' job, Scott is selected for 'cowboy' job, and Adeel is selected for 'programming' job."
```